# JWT con base MySql local 10 puntos, con base cloud db4free o clever MAL, postman error 500 token no existe

Tags: mysql, nodejs, backend, postman, jwt

Ante todo, gracias por interesarse en darme una mano, pongo en contexto, tengo mi backend en nodejs con jwt, tengo una base mysql y el front react en la misma pc, con el postman hago una creación de usuario POST y todo bien me tira el token, y crea el usuario, luego puedo entrar por primer vez desde el front y generar mas usuarios y hacer cualquier cosa.

El problema es que quiero subir todo, el back y el front no es problema porque ya los tengo arriba y funcionan bien y responden, el tema es que hice una base en db4free y en clever, ambas para probar, importe los datos de la base local, para tener todos los datos en las cloud y todo ok, pero cuando ingreso los datos de cualquiera de las dos db cloud en mi back y quiero con el postman generar un nuevo usuario, me tira error 500.

Probe en ambas bd y lo mismo, pero si agrego la base local , todo de 10.

Con el workbench me conecto todo ok y veo los datos de las 3.

Alguna idea ??, gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error que tira es :

```
> node app.js

Server en el puerto 8000
POST /api/empleados/crear 500 120.964 ms - 80
```

agrego empleados.js

```
const empleados = require("../models").Empleados;
const tiposEmpleado = require("../models").TiposEmpleado;
const validations = require("../helpers/validations");
const auth = require("../services/authServices");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const { success, badRequest, forbidden, exception } = require("../helpers/responses");
const BCRYPT_ROUNDS = require("../config/config.js").BCRYPT_ROUNDS;

const attributes = [
  "id",
  "nombre",
  "apellido",
  "email",
  "dni",
  "Dto",
  "estado",
  "createdAt",
  "updatedAt",
];

const includes = [
  {
    attributes: ["id", "tipoEmpleado"],
    model: tiposEmpleado,
    as: "tipo",
  },
];

module.exports = {
  async login(req, res) {
    var validationsArr = [];

    validations.validateRequired(req, "email", validationsArr);
    validations.validateRequired(req, "password", validationsArr);

    if (validationsArr.length > 0) {
      return badRequest(res, validationsArr);
    }

    try {
      let response = await auth.login({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
      });

      return success(res, {
        empleado: {
          id: response.id,
          nombre: response.nombre,
          apellido: response.apellido,
          email: response.email,
          password: response.password,
          tipo: response.tipo,
          Dto: response.Dto,
        },
        token: response.token,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return forbidden(res);
    }
  },

  crear(req, res) {
    var validationsArr = [];

    validations.validateRequired(req, "nombre", validationsArr);
    validations.validateRequired(req, "apellido", validationsArr);
    validations.validateRequired(req, "email", validationsArr);
    validations.validateRequired(req, "password", validationsArr);
    validations.validateRequired(req, "idTipoEmpleado", validationsArr);
    validations.validateRequired(req, "Dto", validationsArr);

    if (validationsArr.length > 0) {
      return badRequest(res, validationsArr);
    }

    try {
      return empleados
        .findOrCreate({
          where: {
            email: req.body.email,
          },
          defaults: {
            idTipoEmpleado: req.body.idTipoEmpleado,
            nombre: req.body.nombre,
            apellido: req.body.apellido,
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, BCRYPT_ROUNDS),
            email: req.body.email,
            dni: req.body.dni,
            Dto: req.body.Dto,
            estado: true,
          },
        })
        .then(async (empleado) => {
          let response = await auth.register(empleado[0].dataValues);

          return success(res, {
            empleado: {
              id: response.id,
              idTipoEmpleado: response.idTipoEmpleado,
              nombre: response.nombre,
              apellido: response.apellido,
              email: response.email,
              Dto: response.Dto,
            },
            token: response.token,
          });
        })

        .catch(() => exception(res, "Ocurrió un error al crear un empleado"));
    } catch (e) {
      return exception(res, "Ocurrió un error al crear la creacion de un empleado");
    }
  },

  listar(req, res) {

    var where = {};

    if(req.query.idTipoEmpleado !== null && req.query.idTipoEmpleado !== undefined){
      where = { idTipoEmpleado: req.query.idTipoEmpleado };
    }

    return empleados
      .findAll({
        where: where,
        attributes: attributes,
        include: includes,
      })
      .then(async (data) => success(res, { empleados: data }))
      .catch(() => exception(res, "Ocurrió un error al listar"));
  },

  obtener(req, res) {
    var validationsArr = [];

    validations.validateRequiredQueryString(req, "id", validationsArr);

    if (validationsArr.length > 0) {
      return badRequest(res, validationsArr);
    }

    return empleados
      .findOne({
        attributes: attributes,
        include: includes,
        where: {
          id: req.query.id,
        },
      })
      .then(async (empleado) => success(res, { empleado: empleado }))
      .catch(() => exception(res, "Ocurrió un error al obtener"));
  },

  obtenerPorDni(req, res) {
    var validationsArr = [];

    validations.validateRequiredQueryString(req, "dni", validationsArr);

    if (validationsArr.length > 0) {
      return badRequest(res, validationsArr);
    }

    return empleados
      .findOne({
        attributes: attributes,
        include: includes,
        where: { dni: req.query.dni },
      })
      .then(async (empleado) => success(res,  { empleado: empleado }))
      .catch(() => exception(res, "Ocurrió un error al obtener"));
  },

  obtenerPorId(req, res) {
    var validationsArr = [];

    validations.validateRequiredQueryString(req, "id", validationsArr);

    if (validationsArr.length > 0) {
      return badRequest(res, validationsArr);
    }

    return empleados
      .findOne({
        attributes: attributes,
        include: includes,
        where: { nombre: req.query.nombre},
      })
      .then(async (empleado) => success(res,  { empleado: empleado }))
      .catch(() => exception(res, "Ocurrió un error al obtener"));
  },


  editar(req, res) {
    var validationsArr = [];

    validations.validateRequired(req, "id", validationsArr);
    validations.validateRequired(req, "nombre", validationsArr);
    validations.validateRequired(req, "apellido", validationsArr);
    validations.validateRequired(req, "idTipoEmpleado", validationsArr);
    validations.validateRequired(req, "Dto", validationsArr);
    validations.validateRequired(req, "estado", validationsArr);

    if(req.body.idTipoEmpleado === "1" || req.body.idTipoEmpleado === 1){
      validations.validateRequired(req, validationsArr);
    }

    if (validationsArr.length > 0) {
      return badRequest(res, validationsArr);
    }

    return empleados
      .update(
        {
          idTipoEmpleado: req.body.idTipoEmpleado,
          nombre: req.body.nombre,
          apellido: req.body.apellido,
          password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, BCRYPT_ROUNDS),
          email: req.body.email,
          dni: req.body.dni,
          Dto: req.body.Dto,
          estado: req.body.estado,
        },
        {
          where: { id: req.body.id },
        }
      )
      .then(async (data) => success(res, { message: data[0] > 0 ? "Se editó correctamente." : "No se editaron datos." }))
      .catch(() => exception(res, "Ocurrió un error al obtener"));
  },

  eliminar(req, res) {
    var validationsArr = [];

    validations.validateRequired(req, "id", validationsArr);

    if (validationsArr.length > 0) {
      return badRequest(res, validationsArr);
    }

    return empleados
      .destroy({
        where: { id: req.body.id },
      })
      .then(async (data) => success(res, { message: data[0] > 0 ? "Se eliminó correctamente." : "No se eliminaron datos." }))
      .catch(() => exception(res, "Ocurrió un error al eliminar"));
  },
};
```

tambien me tira el siguiente error , si en el postman seteo en x-www-form-urlencoded

```
TypeError: req.body.hasOwnProperty is not a function
    at Object.validateRequiredProp (C:\Users\Oscar\TORNADOAPPVISION\Backend\helpers\validations.js:17:21)
    at Object.validateRequired (C:\Users\Oscar\TORNADOAPPVISION\Backend\helpers\validations.js:25:15)
    at crear (C:\Users\Oscar\TORNADOAPPVISION\Backend\controllers\empleados.js:67:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Oscar\TORNADOAPPVISION\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Oscar\TORNADOAPPVISION\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Oscar\TORNADOAPPVISION\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Oscar\TORNADOAPPVISION\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Oscar\TORNADOAPPVISION\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Oscar\TORNADOAPPVISION\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:341:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Oscar\TORNADOAPPVISION\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at C:\Users\Oscar\TORNADOAPPVISION\Backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\Oscar\TORNADOAPPVISION\Backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (C:\Users\Oscar\TORNADOAPPVISION\Backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\Oscar\TORNADOAPPVISION\Backend\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

Comment: Parece que es dificil el tema ...

Comment: Sin código asociado, sin logs de error (si los hay), sin versión del software base que estás usando. Sí, en esas condiciones es dificilísimo! ;)  Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: No basta con que resumas el error. Pon aquí el error completo. Y comparte todo **cómo texto** para que puedan replicar tu problema o revisarlo mejor. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Una buena pregunta siempre termina reabierta :)

Comment: @Alfabravo, si tenes razon ... ahi edite con código, no se que más podria ayudar.

Comment: Funciono con una instancia de AWS !!! instale todo como si fuera local y anduvo.